A different filter value results in a different (slower) query plan
I am executing the following query in Postgres 15 with the Timescale extension on an alerts table to get the latest alert for a username.
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM alerts_alerts
WHERE username IN ('<username_here>')
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1

For most usernames, the query executes quickly, under 150ms. However, for some usernames, it takes longer. Almost all databases have around the same number of alerts, around 450, and most of them have fairly recent data, all within the past 6 months.
Here's the Explain Analyze for the problematic username:
"Limit  (cost=0.29..2262.68 rows=1 width=86) (actual time=36129.346..36129.370 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Custom Scan (ChunkAppend) on alerts_alerts  (cost=0.29..2262.68 rows=1 width=86) (actual time=36129.344..36129.368 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Order: alerts_alerts.""timestamp"" DESC"
"        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_234_chunk_alerts_alerts_timestamp_idx_1 on _hyper_1_234_chunk  (cost=0.29..2262.68 rows=1 width=89) (actual time=5.795..5.796 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Filter: ((username)::text = 'username_long_query'::text)"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 30506"
"        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_233_chunk_alerts_alerts_timestamp_idx_1 on _hyper_1_233_chunk  (cost=0.29..4337.82 rows=1 width=91) (actual time=11.112..11.112 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Filter: ((username)::text = 'username_long_query'::text)"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 59534"
            [   ...     Cut redundant log lines here    ...    ]
"        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_156_chunk_alerts_alerts_timestamp_idx_1 on _hyper_1_156_chunk  (cost=0.42..11418.54 rows=2591 width=80) (never executed)"
"              Filter: ((username)::text = 'username_long_query'::text)"
"        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_155_chunk_alerts_alerts_timestamp_idx_1 on _hyper_1_155_chunk  (cost=0.29..7353.95 rows=749 width=84) (never executed)"
"              Filter: ((username)::text = 'username_long_query'::text)"
            [   ...     Cut redundant log lines here    ...    ]
"Planning Time: 13.154 ms"
"Execution Time: 36129.923 ms"

Now, this is the Explain Analyze for the usernames that execute quickly:
"Limit  (cost=471.73..471.73 rows=1 width=458) (actual time=1.672..1.691 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=471.73..472.76 rows=414 width=458) (actual time=1.671..1.689 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: _hyper_1_234_chunk.""timestamp"" DESC"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB"
"        ->  Append  (cost=0.29..469.66 rows=414 width=457) (actual time=1.585..1.654 rows=210 loops=1)"
"              ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_234_chunk_alerts_alerts_fleet_a3933a38_1 on _hyper_1_234_chunk  (cost=0.29..2.49 rows=1 width=372) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: ((username)::text = 'username_value'::text)"
"              ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_233_chunk_alerts_alerts_fleet_a3933a38_1 on _hyper_1_233_chunk  (cost=0.29..2.37 rows=1 width=385) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: ((username)::text = 'username_value'::text)"
            [   ...     Cut redundant log lines here    ...    ]
"              ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_1_83_chunk  (cost=0.00..1.12 rows=1 width=504) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: ((username)::text = 'username_value'::text)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 10"
"              ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_1_81_chunk  (cost=0.00..1.12 rows=1 width=504) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: ((username)::text = 'username_value'::text)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 10"
"Planning Time: 899.811 ms"
"Execution Time: 2.613 ms"

Preliminary research suggests doing maintenance on the database table. After executing the vacuum command, the queries were executed again but the results did not change.
It should also be noted that there are other usernames that use the "problematic" planning, but the execution time is still quick.
Not sure how to resolve this discrepancy in query execution time. It could be useful to add another index, but as I'm new to PostgreSQL, I'm currently not sure about the best approach to this.

This is not a PostgreSQL question, but a question about the (unspecified) PostgreSQL extension that implements the Custom Scan (ChunkAppend).

Sounds like TimescaleDB.

Your query shows WHERE username IN ('<username_here>') - indicating a list of user names, but your query plans show (username)::text = '...'::text - indicating a single user name. Which is it?

@ErwinBrandstetter It is just one username.

"Filter by one column (username), order by another (timestamp), LIMIT 1!"
It's the age-old battle between two possible approaches:

Traverse an index on timestamp, filter for the right username(s). The first hit accomplishes the task. That's what happens in your first plan:

"        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_234_chunk_alerts_alerts_timestamp_idx_1 on _hyper_1_234_chunk  (cost=0.29..2262.68 rows=1 width=89) (actual time=5.795..5.796 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Filter: ((username)::text = 'username_long_query'::text)"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 30506"

Just repeated over and over for all partitions in your Timescale hypertable (they call partitions "chunks").
It works well, unless the first hit is far off in the past - like in the case at hand. If Postgres doesn't have valid information to work with (column statistics: most-common-values list, n_distinct setting), it can fall into this trap.

Use an index on username to retrieve all rows for the given username(s), then sort and take the latest. That's what your second plan shows:

"        ->  Append  (cost=0.29..469.66 rows=414 width=457) (actual time=1.585..1.654 rows=210 loops=1)"
"              ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_234_chunk_alerts_alerts_fleet_a3933a38_1 on _hyper_1_234_chunk  (cost=0.29..2.49 rows=1 width=372) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: ((username)::text = 'username_value'::text)"

That's (much) more efficient, if there are few qualifying rows and even the latest one is buried under many newer, not-qualifying rows.
If your queries only filter for a single username at a time, a multicolumn index on (username, timestamp DESC) would be perfect.
But the Timescale hypertable you have (I assume) is partitioned on the timestamp column ("time-partitioned into chunks"). That's optimized for queries on timestamp first, so the best strategy becomes tricky. Typically, still said multicolumn index. Then Postgres/Timescale still has to look into every chunk (or just the index), starting with the youngest, until it finds the first entry for the given username. But now it does not have to plough through all rows just to find nothing and state Rows Removed by Filter: 30506" - which is all rows in the chunk in the example.
For only few distinct usernames, you could sub-partition your hypertables. In bloomy Timescale parlance "add a space-partitioning dimension to a hypertable". But that's inefficient for too many distinct usernames.
The best course of action depends on the complete picture: cardinalities, write frequency, data distribution, hardware resources, server configuration, Postgres and Timescale version, ... probably beyond the scope of a simple question here.
Related:

Postgres sometimes uses inferior index for WHERE a IN (...) ORDER BY b LIMIT N
How to speed up single-column date range query in Postgres?
Can spatial index help a "range - order by - limit" query


Thanks. I just realized the mistake in using WHERE IN (), there's only one username ever so there's no use passing it as an array. I'll also check adding in an index for the username and timestamp desc. Thank you!
